# Hiding buttons in a UIViewController from a UIView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a UIView class that is loaded in to a UIViewController as a subview, to capture touches and draw them to the screen (a simple drawing app). I want to hide some buttons in the UIViewController when drawing begins. In the UIViewController (DrawingController.m) viewDidLoad method:

```
//init the draw screen
drawScreen=[[MyLineDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[drawScreen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:drawScreen];
```

I have a method in the UIViewController (DrawingController.m) that is hiding my colour picker, brush size buttons etc that are present within the UIViewController. The hide method works fine when called from the same class (DrawingController.m). Basically when the -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method is called within the UIView class (MyLineDrawingView.m) I am hoping to hide the buttons:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    DrawingController *drawController = [[DrawingController alloc] init];
    [drawController hideDrawIcons];

}
```

I've added some logging to the hideDrawIcons method within the UIViewController and it is getting called, but all of my hiding code is not working:

```
self.undoBtn.hidden = YES;
```

I suspect this is because I am making a new instance of the UIViewController class with DrawingController *drawController = [[DrawingController alloc] init]; - but I'm not sure how to do things differently?

I have of course exposed the correct method in the DrawingController.h header file, to be able to call it from the UIView class (MyLineDrawingView.m):

```
-(void)hideDrawIcons;
```

Hopefully all of that makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, obviously I have omitted some code from the touchesBegan method that is handling the drawing etc, everything is working fine apart from getting the buttons within the UIViewController hidden when touches being (and I will of course show them again when touching ends) - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You do not need to make create new instance of DrawingController.
All you need yo have pointer of your DrawingController in your View class. If you want to know more about this technology you can read about Delegate pattern. If not, here is simple steps.

Add protocol in your MyLineDrawingView.h file ( or you can create separated file for it )

```
@protocol MyLineDrawingProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)hideDrawIcons;

@end
```

In your DrawingController.h

```
@interface DrawingController <MyLineDrawingProtocol>
{
    // members ....
}

@end
```

In your MyLineDrawingView.h

```
@interface MyLineDrawingView
{
    // members ....
}
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <MyLineDrawingProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

Set delegate for your view

```
//init the draw screen
drawScreen=[[MyLineDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
drawScreen.delegate = self;// self is a pointer of DrawingController
[drawScreen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:drawScreen];
```

And last change. Call hideDrawIcons method for delegate ( DrawingController )

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(hideDrawIcons)] )
        [self.delegate hideDrawIcons];

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! I get an error on the drawScreen.delegate = self; line, it says Property delegate not found on object of type MyLineDrawingView* - one thing that I think might make a difference, in DrawingController.h I have the following variable set: @interface DrawingController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    
    MyLineDrawingView *drawScreen;
    
}

Comment: most likely you did not add @property (nonatomic,weak) id <MyLineDrawingProtocol> delegate; this line in your MyLineDrawingView.h. I am sorry. I will edit formatting of my answer

Comment: Thanks very much, this solution worked after I added that line to MyLineDrawingView.h

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're creating a new copy of the view controller in your view, which is wrong. What you want is to have a reference to the actual view controller. Here's how you can do it:

In MyLineDrawingView, declare a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) DrawingController *drawingController;
```

Note that it is declared as weak, which prevents a [retain cycle](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-30-dealing-with-retain-cycles.html).

When instantiating the view:

```
drawScreen=[[MyLineDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
drawScreen.drawingController = self; // pass the actual view controller instance to the drawScreen object.
```

Finally, in MyLineDrawingView:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     [self.drawingController hideDrawIcons];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, a couple errors.

I get an error for the line

    drawScreen.drawingController = self;

Which says 'Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with ARC'

. I also get an error for the line

    @property (nonatomic, weak) DrawingController *drawingController;

The error is Unknown type name 'DrawingController' and 'Property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type

Comment: You need to include the header for DrawingController in `MyLineDrawingView.h`. Without that, MyLineDrawingView doesn't "know" about DrawingController. After you make that change, the 2nd error should go away too.

Comment: Actually I am getting those errors with the header included in MyLineDrawingView.h

Comment: The errors you quote say that `DrawingController` is an unknown type. Something must be wrong with the  way you include DrawingController.h.

Comment: If I try just including DrawingController.h (#import "DrawingController.h" - before I was including it in the .m file) in MyLineDrawingView.h I get the following error for the line when I am declaring MyLineDrawingView within the header for DrawingController.h - I should have included this code before sorry: @interface DrawingController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {  MyLineDrawingView *drawScreen; }, the error is Unknown type name MyLineDrawingView - thanks

Comment: Try this: don't include `DrawingController.h` in `MyLineDrawingView.h`, but instead in `MyLineDrawingView.m`. In the beginning of `MyLineDrawingView.h`, forward-declare `DrawingController` by adding this line: `@class DrawingController;`.

Comment: It lets me compile if I do that, but then additing @property (nonatomic, weak) DrawingController *drawingController; to MyLineDrawingView.h gives two errors: Uknown type name DrawingController and Property with weak attribute must be of object type - thanks for your help so far