# Display values in ParentView after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have 2 view parentView and SubView. I am called the subView from my parentView:

```
subView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"subView"];    
[self presentViewController:subView animated:YES completion:nil]; 
[self.view addSubview:subView.view];
```

In my subView I have some functionalities and storing the values in a string. I want to display these values in a label in my parentView after I dismiss the subView:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

How can I pass these values to my parentView and display it over there after dismissViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding subView.view as a subview to your view -- that's unnecessary, since after the presentation, self.view is removed from the window hierarchy anyway.

Comment: you can do this with any ios pattern like (delegate, global variable, notification etc). best suited in your case in delegate pattern. for understanding delegate pattern link-1 http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns/ link-2 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have properties in your SubView and before calling [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]; take values from SubView and show in parentView
2. You can set your parent view as delegate of subView and transfer values to parent view.

By the way. Why are you calling addSubview: after presentViewController: ?

**EDIT**

Check this answer

[Hiding buttons in a UIViewController from a UIView delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559560/hiding-buttons-in-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uiview-delegate?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I have tableView in my subViews, the user selected some values and once its dones the selected values are displayed in the parentView. I tried setting as delegate, but no luck. Is there any sample code which can help me out?